# How do I fix this configuration error in unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

So I'm trying to build my app and I keep getting this error. I had to update my app for the new Unity Ads API, I also upgraded the unity editor while I was at it, and I've been getting this error ever since. I've tried doing what it suggests, but I have no idea why it's not working. Here's the full error:

````
WARNING:The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You can add the following to your build.gradle instead:
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
    }
}

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseApplicationId
> Task :launcher:analyticsRecordingRelease
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :launcher:processReleaseMainManifest
> Task :launcher:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:processApplicationManifestReleaseForBundle
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :launcher:configureReleaseDependencies
> Task :launcher:parseReleaseIntegrityConfig
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifestForPackage
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareReleaseArtProfile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseArtProfile
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
>45 actionable tasks: 45 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:196)```

it looked to me like the meat of the error was in the top bit, but again, I tried doing what it suggested and it just turns out the same error every time. I have absolutely no idea how to fix this and some help would be very much appreciated!
````

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. I'd look at the editor.log file and search for `stderr` to see the factual error.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, Where would I find that file? When I look under the logs folder I don't see it, all I see is `ApiUpdaterCheck.txt`, `Packages-Update.log`, and `shadercompiler-UnityShaderCompiler-0.log`

Comment: You can open it from the console or find the file and open it that way. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html